# What is python's _random?

Tags: python, python-2.7

If you open `random.py` to see how it works, its class `Random` subclasses `_random.Random`:

```
import _random

class Random(_random.Random):
    """Random number generator base class used by bound module functions.

    Used to instantiate instances of Random to get generators that don't
    share state.  Especially useful for multi-threaded programs, creating
    a different instance of Random for each thread, and using the jumpahead()
    method to ensure that the generated sequences seen by each thread don't
    overlap.

    Class Random can also be subclassed if you want to use a different basic
    generator of your own devising: in that case, override the following
    methods: random(), seed(), getstate(), setstate() and jumpahead().
    Optionally, implement a getrandbits() method so that randrange() can cover
    arbitrarily large ranges.

    """
```

I can find the file `random.py` easily by doing:

```
In [1]: import sys
In [2]: print random.__file__
/usr/lib/python2.7/random.pyc
```

However `_random` does not have this variable:

```
In [3]: _random.__file__
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-295-a62b7df330e2> in <module>()
----> 1 _random.__file__

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

So what is `_random`, why does `random` subclass it, and where can I find its corresponding file?

Comment: That's a reference to the C implementation: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_randommodule.c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is common practice to use a leading underscore for modules implemented in C. Often the pattern `_mod` for this C module and `mod` for a Python module that imports this `_mod` is used. You will find this for several modules of the standard library. Typically, you should use `mod` and not `_mod`.

On Mac OS X there is a file:

```
_random.so
```

In the directory of the shared libraries used by Python.

Just type the module name at the interactive prompt to see the path:

```
>>> _random
<module '_random' from '/path/to/python/sharedlibs/_random.so'>
```

BTW, not all modules you can import have a file associated with them. Some are part of the Python executeable, the builtin modules:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.builtin_module_names
('_ast', '_codecs', '_collections', '_functools', '_imp', '_io', '_locale',
 '_operator', '_signal', '_sre', '_stat', '_string', '_symtable', '_thread',
 '_tracemalloc', '_warnings', '_weakref', 'atexit', 'builtins', 'errno', 
 'faulthandler', 'gc', 'itertools', 'marshal', 'posix', 'pwd', 'sys', 
 'time', 'xxsubtype', 'zipimport')
```

So if you get on your platform:

```
>>> _random
_random <module '_random' (built-in)>
```

Than `_random` is part of Python executeable itself.

In the C source [_randommodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_randommodule.c#L564) you can find the methods of `Random` that are made available for use in Python:

```
static PyMethodDef random_methods[] = {
    {"random",          (PyCFunction)random_random,  METH_NOARGS,
        PyDoc_STR("random() -> x in the interval [0, 1).")},
    {"seed",            (PyCFunction)random_seed,  METH_VARARGS,
        PyDoc_STR("seed([n]) -> None.  Defaults to current time.")},
    {"getstate",        (PyCFunction)random_getstate,  METH_NOARGS,
        PyDoc_STR("getstate() -> tuple containing the current state.")},
    {"setstate",          (PyCFunction)random_setstate,  METH_O,
        PyDoc_STR("setstate(state) -> None.  Restores generator state.")},
    {"getrandbits",     (PyCFunction)random_getrandbits,  METH_VARARGS,
        PyDoc_STR("getrandbits(k) -> x.  Generates an int with "
                  "k random bits.")},
    {NULL,              NULL}           /* sentinel */
};
```

Compare to:

```
>>> [x for x in dir(_random.Random) if not x.startswith('__')]
['getrandbits', 'getstate', 'jumpahead', 'random', 'seed', 'setstate']
```

Comment: Ok so at the end of the `seed` method you see `super(Random, self).seed(a)`. So `super(Random)` is actually the C-version of Random, is that right? However, opening the file that you linked I can't find the function `seed()` there...

Comment: "Just type the module name at the interactive prompt to see the path:" That's not what I get. I get this: `>>> _random
<module '_random' (built-in)>`

Comment: OK. I am on Mac. Maybe it is different on other platforms.

Comment: I've marked this as answered. But I'd suggest that you edit back in that link to the source code repo in the response body. Originally it was there.

Comment: Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

It's a reference to C Python's [_random module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_randommodule.c#L521). It is implemented in C, so there is no .py file to find.