# Random stealing calls to child initializer

Tags: python, subclass

There's a situation involving sub-classing I can't figure out.

I'm sub-classing `Random` (the reason is besides the point). Here's a basic example of what I have:

```
import random

class MyRandom(random.Random):
    def __init__(self, x):  # x isn't used here, but it's necessary to show the problem.
        print("Before")
        super().__init__()  # Nothing passed to parent
        print("After")

MyRandom([])
```

The above code, when run, gives the following error (and doesn't print "Before"):

```
>>> import test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\_\PycharmProjects\first\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    MyRandom([])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

To me, this doesn't make any sense. Somehow, the argument to `MyRandom` is apparently being passed directly to `Random.__init__` even though I'm not passing it along, and the list is being treated as a seed. `"Before"` never prints, so apparently my initializer is never even being called.

I thought maybe this was somehow due to the parent of `Random` being implemented in C and this was causing weirdness, but a similar case with `list` sub-classing doesn't yield an error saying that ints aren't iterable:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, y):
        print("Before")
        super().__init__() 
        print("After")


r = MyList(2)  # Prints "Before", "After"
```

---

I have no clue how to even approach this. I rarely ever sub-class, and even rarer is it that I sub-class a built-in, so I must have developed a hole in my knowledge. This is not how I expect sub-classing to work. If anyone can explain what's going on here, I'd appreciate it.

---

Python 3.9

Comment: "I thought maybe this was somehow due to the parent of Random being implemented in C and this was causing weirdness" It should be this; the things implemented in C have to implement `__new__`, which receives the same arguments as `__init__`. But from what I can tell of the source code, the C part of the Random class just uses the generic new and does the fun part in init, as with `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiating a class causes its `__new__` method to be called. It is passed the name of the class **and** the arguments in the constructor call. So `MyRandom([1, 2])` results in the call `MyRandom.__new__(MyRandom, [1, 2])`. ([3.9.10 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__new__#object.__new__)).

Because there isn't a `MyRandom.__new__()` method, the base classes are searched.  `random.Random` does have a `__new__()` method (see `random_new()` in [_randommodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Modules/_randommodule.c)).  So we get a call something like this `random_new(MyRandom, [1, 2])`.

Looking at the C code for `random_new()`, it calls `random_seed(self, [1, 2])`.  Because the second argument isn't Null, or `None`, or an `int`, or a subclass of int, the code calls `PyObject_Hash([1, 2])`. But a list isn't hashable, hence the error.

If `__new__()` returns a instance of the class, then the `__init__()` method is called with the arguments in the constuctor call.

One possible fix is to define a `MyRandom.__new__()` method, which calls `super().__new__()` but only passes the appropriate args.

```
class MyRandom(random.Random):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        #print(f"In __new__: {args=}, {kwargs=}")

        # Random.__new__ expects an optional seed. We are going to 
        # implement out own RNG, so ignore args and kwargs. Pass in a 
        # junk integer value so that Random.__new__ doesn't waste time
        # trying to access urandom or calling time to initialize the MT RNG
        # since we aren't going to use it anyway.
        return super().__new__(cls, 123)
    
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        #print(f"In __init__: {args=}, {kwargs=}")

        # initialize your custom RNG here
        pass
```

Also override the methods: `random()`, `seed()`, `getstate()`, `setstate()`, and optionally `getrandbits()`.

An alternative fix is to only use keyword arguments in the `__init__()` methods of the subclasses. The C code for `random_new()` checks to see if a an instance of random.Random is being created. If true, the code throws and error if there are any keyword arguments. However, if a subclass is being created, any keyword arguments are ignored by `random_new()`, but can be used in the subclass `__init__()`.

```
class MyRandom(random.Random):
    def __init__(self, *, x):  # make x a keyword only argument
        print("Before")
        super().__init__()  # Nothing passed to parent
        print("After")

MyRandom(x=[])
```

Interestingly, in Python 3.10, the code for `random_new` has been changed to raise an error if more that 1 **positional** argument is supplied.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to pass a list into the `Random`'s inheritor and use it in `__init__`.

```py
import random
from typing import List


class MyRandom(random.Random):
    internal_list: List

    def __init__(self, x=None):
        if type(x) is list:
            print(f"Access to the list from `__init__`: {MyRandom.internal_list}")
            super().__init__(MyRandom.internal_list[0])
        else:
            super().__init__(x)

    def __new__(cls, x):
        cls.internal_list = x
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def new_method(self):
        print(f"Access to the list from `new_method`: {MyRandom.internal_list}")

r1 = MyRandom([1, 2])
r1.new_method()
print(r1.random())

r2 = MyRandom([3, 4])
r2.new_method()
print(r2.random())
```

Output:

```
Access to the list from `__init__`: [1, 2]
Access to the list from `new_method`: [1, 2]
0.13436424411240122
Access to the list from `__init__`: [3, 4]
Access to the list from `new_method`: [3, 4]
0.23796462709189137
```

For example purpose, I used `MyRandom.internal_list[0]` to initialize the PRNG. Of course, it's needed to check if the first element exists.

I'm not sure why `__new__` is used when you init `MyRandom`. It's definitely not documented, because in PyCharm implementation I found this:

```
    @staticmethod # known case of __new__
    def __new__(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        """ Create and return a new object.  See help(type) for accurate signature. """
        pass
```

Comment: That last part is in the module `_random` which is the C implementation found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_randommodule.c). What I still couldn't figure out is why `__new__` throws this error. In the C file it [seems like a standard new](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/76dc047a0e88d10aad0405228d56e94438cdd91c/Modules/_randommodule.c#L567) - `PyType_GenericNew`

Comment: @Tomerikoo couldn't it be caused by `random_init` calling `random_seed` on `arg`? I see [hashing in it](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/76dc047a0e88d10aad0405228d56e94438cdd91c/Modules/_randommodule.c#L307).

Comment: Could be. To be honest I'm completely confused by now as I never worked with or inspected C implementation of Python. But to my understanding, `random_seed` is called from `random_init` which I believe is the implementation of the `__init__`. The problem in the question happens *before* `__init__`...

Comment: To be more generic for anything other than `list`, you can use the [`Hashable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Hashable) type: `if not isinstance(x, collections.abc.Hashable)` instead of `if type(x) is list`

Comment: @Tomerikoo in general this approach is definitely more suitable. But in my example it's better to leave `type(x) is list` because later I use `getitem` operator in `super().__init__`.

Comment: Oh you're right alot of the code is intended specifically for lists, I didn't notice. I just thought this could cover cases where a dict is passed instead of a list for example

Answer (score 2):

So there is already [a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70824285/6045800) showing how to *work-around* this issue, but it got me curious as to ***why*** this happens. I couldn't get to a definitive answer, but posting my findings here for anyone who wants to follow through.

---

So we know that when a new instance is created, first `__new__` is called - creating the actual instance (assigning the memory on C-level). Then the newly created instance is passed to the class' `__init__` method.

Now, as the print of "Before" didn't even happen, it is safe to assume that the problem is in the `__new__` method. Indeed, when I override it like:

```py
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    print("in new")
    return super().__new__(cls)
```

No errors were raised and an expected print-out of:

```
in new
Before
After
```

Once I added `*args` to the `super` call:

```
return super().__new__(cls, *args)
```

The same error was back. So this must be an issue in `Random`'s `__new__`.

Inspecting the code with Pycharm, `Random` doesn't override its `__new__` method, but the class signature is:

```
class Random(_random.Random):
```

Trying to inspect this parent class shows a bunch of methods only containing `pass` in them. This seemed weird but after a quick search, I found out (for some it is probably not a surprise) that [modules starting with `_` are C implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41473958/what-is-pythons-random). And `_random`'s C implementation is [`_randommodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_randommodule.c).

Now, I don't have much knowledge or experience with inspecting C implementations of Python, but I found what seems to be [the basic slots of the `Random` class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d75a51bea3c2442f81d38ff850b81b8b7f3330f0/Modules/_randommodule.c#L564):

```c
static PyType_Slot Random_Type_slots[] = {
    {Py_tp_doc, (void *)random_doc},
    {Py_tp_methods, random_methods},
    {Py_tp_new, PyType_GenericNew},
    {Py_tp_init, random_init},
    {Py_tp_free, PyObject_Free},
    {0, 0},
};
```

My own understanding from this is that the class' `__init__` is mapped to [`random_init`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d75a51bea3c2442f81d38ff850b81b8b7f3330f0/Modules/_randommodule.c#L529), and the class' `__new__` is mapped to [`PyType_GenericNew`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a1444f43584af0f7a0af72aa06ba0a86ae5a87a2/Objects/typeobject.c#L1198). But as its name suggests, `PyType_GenericNew` is just a generic object creator assigning the necessary amount of memory for the object. Its body is the single line:

```c
PyType_GenericNew(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    return type->tp_alloc(type, 0);
}
```

The `args` are not even used.

On the other hand, the `random_init` function calls [`random_seed`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d75a51bea3c2442f81d38ff850b81b8b7f3330f0/Modules/_randommodule.c#L275) which [does have some hashing in it](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d75a51bea3c2442f81d38ff850b81b8b7f3330f0/Modules/_randommodule.c#L307):

```
Py_hash_t hash = PyObject_Hash(arg);
```

But then again, we established that the `__init__` is not even called yet, at which point I'm stumped...